# quoting a sentence in Present Simple: can I change the tense?

Tags: quotations

If I quote a sentence in Present Simple (not just paraphrase), should I replace present forms with past forms or leave them as they are?

In other words, what are rules or conventions regarding quoting? Does it mean that I'm not allowed to change anything (otherwise, it would be misquoting) or I can — or even have to — apply the same rules that exist for indirect speech (like, 'he said he **would** be happy to host a Christmas party')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are quoting, then quote the actual words (though there are mechanisms for omitting, emending, explaining, and other editorial actions if necessarily.

So

> "I'm going out", he said.
>
> He said he was going out.

Comment: No! My question wasn't about reported speech! It was specifically about quoting. Based on your example, which sentence is correct: «he said "I'm going out"», «he said "he's going out"», «he said "I was going out"», «he said "he was going out"»? Here, it looks like direct speech, but in my case, for example, I'm quoting a subordinate clause. Should I keep the present tense or switch it to the past?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. If the words he used were "I'm going out", then you quote it as _He said, "I'm going out"_, or _He said, "I'm happy to host a Christmas party"_. Incidentally, guillemets («») are not customary in English.

Comment: I know, but I hadn't those suspended paired commas at hand (I have hot buttons for "gulimets" or whatever it's called). Suppose, someone named Mike said to his friend John, "I'll be an hour late for the party because I need to take my son to the dentist". And then John texts to their mutual pal Dereck this, "Mike said he would be an hour later «because I need to take my son to the dentist»". So, your point is that it's perfectly okay to do like this? Not 'he' or 'needed'?

Comment: It's an unusual thing to do, putting part of the sentence as a direct quote like that, and you would only do it if there were some special meaning to doing so: in this case, probably, that you didn't believe the excuse was genuine. But if you did quote it like that, then yes, "I need".

Answer (score 1):

Quoting speech means reproducing *exactly* what the original speaker said, except possibly omitting 'er', 'um', etc.

> Direct speech gives the actual words that a speaker used.

[Collins Dictionary](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/quotation-marks-or)

Direct speech: John said "I'm tired."

Reported speech shifts tenses back, like this: John said he was tired.

In conversation, when an 'ambiguous' set of words, e.g. John said I'm a fool, is spoken, the hearer has access to context, and verbal and non-verbal cues, and the less likely of the two possible meanings is discarded, and this usually works OK. Mental processing happens, and it is more than merely decoding the sounds of the words. Often, when quoting speech, a speaker will change his/her voice slightly, or insert clarifying words (e.g. John said **that** I'm a fool), or even resort to reported speech (John said that he was (or is) a fool).

Comment: It can be confusing in spoken speech, can't it? I mean who was tired, the speaker or John? There are no vocal quote marks when you talk (you can use gestures, but it's not really part of English)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Please clarify. If John said "I'm tired", then it is quite clear that John is/was tired. Who else could be tired?

Comment: If you say (SAY, I'm stressing, not write) 'John said «I'm tired»', it's not clear whether the implied sentence is 'John said, «I'm tired»' or 'John said (that) I'm tired'

Comment: OK I see. 1. John said "I'm a fool." - John said that he himself was a fool. 2. John said I'm a fool. - John called _me_ a fool. See the difference? Does this explain?

Comment: Why do you explain the difference between the sentences? I'm saying, 'Isn't it confusing (that those sentences sound exactly the same)?' If so, wouldn't it be wiser to switch the preposition to 'he'? If so, would it still be grammatically direct speech/quoting?

Comment: In conversation, when an 'ambiguous' set of words, e.g. John said I'm a fool, is spoken, the hearer has access to context, and verbal and non-verbal cues, and the less likely of the two possible meanings is discarded, and this usually woeks OK. Mental processing happens, and it is more than merely decoding the sounds of the words.   Often, when quoting speech, a speaker will change his/her voice slightly, or insert clarifying words (e.g. John said that I'm a fool), or even resort to reported speech.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev: _John said I'm tired_ as reported speech is _very_ unlikely, because the tenses don't work. It's almost certain that he was quoting.